# OAuth {"error":"invalid_client"} grant type "client credential" - C# ASP.Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, owin

I keep getting invalid client while trying to request a token from my local endpoint using postman or curl. It is just a ASP.NET MVC project with WebAPI enabled (the check box when you create the project).I have got one class MyAuthorizationServerProvider.cs which has got the below code

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;

namespace OAuth2App.Provider
{
    public class OAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            string clientId;
            string clientSecret;
            Guid clientIdGuid;
            if (!context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret))
            {
                context.TryGetFormCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret);
            }
            if (null == context.ClientId || null == clientSecret || !Guid.TryParse(clientId, out clientIdGuid))
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_credentials", "A valid client_Id and client_Secret must be provided.");
                context.Rejected();
                return;
            }
            //validate aginstdb or config: GetClient(clientIdGuid, clientSecret);  
            bool isValidClient = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"] == clientId && ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"] == clientSecret;
            if (!isValidClient)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_credentials", "A valid client_Id and client_Secret must be provided.");
                context.Rejected();
                return;
            }
            await Task.Run(() => context.Validated(clientId));
        }
        public override async Task GrantClientCredentials(OAuthGrantClientCredentialsContext context)
        {
            Guid clientId;
            Guid.TryParse(context.ClientId, out clientId);
            //validate aginstdb or config: GetByClientId(clientId);  
            bool client = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"] == clientId.ToString().ToUpper();
            if (!client)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Invaild client.");
                context.Rejected();
                return;
            }
            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("LoggedOn", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
            await Task.Run(() => context.Validated(claimsIdentity));
        }
        public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
        {
            if (context.TokenIssued)
            {
                context.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(3600);
            }
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    }
}
```

I have got another OWIN startup class as below

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using OAuth2App.Provider;
using Owin;
using System;
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(OAuth2App.Startup))]
namespace OAuth2App
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var oAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true, // need set to false in PROD  
                    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth2/token"),
                    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60), //token expiration time  
                    Provider = new OAuthProvider(),
            };            
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        }
    }
}
```

My web.config app settimgs section is as below

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="clientId" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
    <add key="clientSecret" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

When I try to fire a post request, the below is what I get in postman. While debugging, I see that the context object always has the clientID field as null. Can someone please point out what I ding wrong ?

```
public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
```

[image: PostmanCall]

Comment: Anyone please can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the below code, behaving buggy. I basically changed it to an if statement and also removed context.rejected

```
bool isValidClient = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"] == clientId && ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"] == clientSecret;
        if (!isValidClient)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_credentials", "A valid client_Id and client_Secret must be provided.");
            context.Rejected();
            return;
        }
```

// Changed to

```
If(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"] == clientId && ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"] == clientSecret)
    {
context.SetError("invalid_credentials", "A valid client_Id and client_Secret must be provided.");
            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that the question was about grant_type="client_credentials", but if anyone has the same problem, but with **grant_type="password"**, here is how I solved it:

1. Make sure you send data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded
2. make sure you send Authorization header with base64-encoded value "yourclientid:clientsecret".
3. In request body you only send: username,password and grant_type
   Here is how the request looks in Fiddler
   [image]

**OPTIONAL:**
Another thing - I implemented my custom IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator validator, in order for validating the username/password against SQL Server with Entity Framework and making the login process successfull.

NOTE: later it appeared, that I don`t need to add my own IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, sinde Identity Server 4 takes care of username/password validation itself, but I thought it would be nice just to post some code on how to create such validator if anyone needs it :)

```
 public class MyResoureceOwnerPasswordValidator : IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

    public MyResoureceOwnerPasswordValidator(ApplicationDbContext db, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
    {
        _db = db;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }
    public async Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
    {
        //var user = _db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.UserName == context.UserName);
        var user = await _signInManager.UserManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);
        if (user != null)
        {
            var res = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, context.Password, false, false);
            var principal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);


            if (res.Succeeded)
            {
                context.Result = new IdentityServer4.Validation.GrantValidationResult(
                   authenticationMethod: "password",
                   subject: user.Id,
                   claims: principal.Claims
                );

            }
        }


    }
}
```

This validator I had to register in Startup.cs

In ConfigureServices method add this:

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
               //some options
            })
.AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
.AddResourceOwnerValidator<MyResoureceOwnerPasswordValidator>();

services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, MyResoureceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**
(I missed the part where you fallback on `TryGetFormCredentials`)

It seems like you need to send the form data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. See the [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.3)

Comment: Does grant_type need to be sent in the headers? You might be right as I haven't worked with this, but the documentation linked doesn't suggest that to me. It would also be helpful if you could provide an example.

Comment: Hey Gabriel, I had tried application/x-www-form-urlencoded, same error :(

Comment: @GabrielGM , anything that you can add ?